Which operations benifit from AlloyDB's columnar angine?
The AlloyDB documentation is confusing for me at this part. There it mentions the list of operations that benefit most from the columnar engine:


Aggregation functions

They only use the following expressions: SUM, MIN, MAX, AVG, and COUNT.
They are at the beginning of the query of a columnar scan.
They are ungrouped, or are grouped-by columns.


ORDER-BY: only if the operator is at the beginning of the query of a columnar scan.
SORT: only if the operator is at the beginning of the query of a columnar scan and sorts only on the base columns of the table or the materialized view.


Source: https://cloud.google.com/alloydb/docs/columnar-engine/about#benefits
I assumed that all of these operations would benefit from the columnar engine if they are applied over base columns (no derived or computed data) but this is mentioned only on the SORT statement.

Does it mean that aggregation functions benefit even if they are applied over computed values?
Why ORDER-BY and SORT are described in separate statements?
Shouldn't ORDER-BY and SORT have the same requirements since the ORDER-BY requirement only makes sense if a SORT is performed underneath?

I appreciate if someone could iluminate me over these concepts.

Columnar engine mean that you do not need to read the whole fields of a row to process it, you can pick only the columns that interest you. Because of that, you can also process column individually, like SUM of AVG that is much more efficient and you can distribute the calculation. In fact, all analytical functions will benefit of the columnar engine.
